# Anyone know about VDADecoder? How to call the create function?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, video, h.264

I read the Apple technical note https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2267/_index.html

I tried calling the sample code "CreateDecoder()" Like this:

```
OSStatus stat = 0;
VDADecoder *decoder = NULL;
CFDataRef data;
char dataStr[] = "data";
data = CFDataCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, (UInt8*)dataStr, 5);   
stat = CreateDecoder(320, 480, 'avc1', data, decoder);
```

But it returned status code -50, which repersents "The operation could't be completed".
Why? How should I call it correctly? I guess it was wrong to pass the "data" string, nut I do not know what to pass actually...

Anyone knows the solution? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my reading of the tech note, you can't just send in any random stream of data for the inAVCCData parameter of CreateDecoder (the string "data" in your case). Check out the part of the tech note which describes decoder configuration keys:

> kVDADecoderConfiguration_avcCData - A CFDataRef containing avcC data
>   from the H.264 bitstream. In a QuickTime movie file, this is the same
>   data which is stored in the image description as the avcC atom.

This is a component of the the transport file that you need to retrieve and pass during the decoder setup.

Comment: I see. I believe that I should read through some introduction about H.264 because I do not even know what avcC is. But right now I just want to know whether VDADecoder available. Can I just change the "data" as a valid avcC data and try initializing it? And where to find valid avcC data example?

Comment: Do you want to know if the acceleration framework is present at all? According to the tech note, if it's Mac OS X 10.6.3 or later, the framework is present. Are you trying to query if the present hardware supports hardware acceleration? It looks like VDADecoderCreate() will return kVDADecoderHardwareNotSupportedErr if not. But you have to give it a valid avcC atom.

Comment: I want to check if the hardware support acceleration. Thank you, you told the keyword and I found another answer. I will study it: http://answerpot.com/showthread.php?578572-Technical+Note+TN2267%2C+Video+Decode+Acceleration

Comment: If you want to check if the hardware supports acceleration, I suppose you could forge an avcC atom and send that into the function. It looks like you have found the authoritative atom details. Alternatively, you could try ripping one out of an existing .mp4 file (look for 'avcC') and planting it in your source code. Use it to query the facilities via VDADecoderCreate() and remember to properly free the resources afterwards.